# Export android framework source code to jar file

Tags: java, android, jar

In [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android), I can download the android framework source code as a source jar file. Now, I want to customize the android framework source code and export my own source jar file.

I am wondering what tool should I use to export such jar file and how can I export the jar file?

Comment: what do you mean by export jar file? Pushing the new jar file to device?

Comment: Export the jar file as library and include to other java project.

Comment: If you are using eclipse or Android studio, you can import the jar file as external library.

Comment: I will add it as an Answer, please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse or Android studio, you can import the jar file as external library. in Android Studio, even you can add as a dependency in the build.gradle file.